# Use numba on classes?

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I can found in 0.6 numba documentation some informations about how to use [numba on classes](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.6/doc/extension_types.html):

```
from numba import jit, void, int_, double

# All methods must be given signatures

@jit
class Shrubbery(object):
    @void(int_, int_)
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        # All instance attributes must be defined in the initializer
        self.width = w
        self.height = h

        # Types can be explicitly specified through casts
        self.some_attr = double(1.0)

    @int_()
    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height

    @void()
    def describe(self):
        print("This shrubbery is ", self.width,
              "by", self.height, "cubits.")
```

But i don't found in [0.16 documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.16.0/index.html). Is it always possible to use numba on classes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last thing I heard about **`numba` class support** was that they [**temporarily** removed it since 0.12](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!searchin/numba-users/class$20support$20siu/numba-users/YqflWZ2XSBI/GBEzARDbOx8J)

Comment: Are there any news or signals you might be aware of about how Travis & his brave `numba` team is about moving this forwards? Have also tried to ask Siu Kwan Lam directly, but fortunately no response has come yet. Thanks for sharing your view in advance.

Comment: Lately I haven't found any time to work with Numba, so I have no further information on this topic. For me, the best way to contact Siu KwanLam was by sending him an Email. He answered any questions really fast. If this doesn't work for you, you should try the [google glroup](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/numba-users)

Comment: Thanks @user4711332, did the same, Siu answered already and expressed some vision for future, if classes would not use `List` and `dictionary` objects.

Comment: Class support is on its way! http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html

Answer (score 6):

As of version 0.23 there is a `numba.jitclass` method. I can say that the following works in version 0.26

```
@numba.jitclass([('width', numba.float64), ('height', numba.float64)])
class Shrubbery(object):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h

    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height

shrubbery = Shrubbery(10, 20)
print(shrubbery.area())
```

The [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html) says that only methods and properties are allowed, so including the `describe` function will unfortunately not work at the moment.